# $A$ and $B$ are nonempty open subsets of the reals with nonempty intersection, and that intersection is a finite set.

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

$A$ and $B$ are nonempty open subsets of the reals with nonempty intersection, and that intersection is a finite set. Give an example if possible, prove if not.

The wording of this confuses me. I feel like this is not possible because something like $(0,1)$ and $(1,10)$ would not have any intersection and once you move one a little like $(0,1.1)$ and $(1,10)$ the area between $1$ and $1.1$ is infinite, no matter how small you make it. I just don't know how to prove this mathematically.

Would the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ be considered open? Or is that one of the ones that is considered neither? Because if it is considered open, then something like $A=(0,10)$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ would work.

Comment: What do you have to prove exactly ? The first line doesn't make sens... (for your last question, it depend on the topology).

Comment: What definition of "open set" are you using?

Comment: Have you tried applying the definition of an open set to $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$? Is there any open interval contained in $A$ and  containing $1$?

Comment: I would have to prove why 2 nonempty open subsets of the reals with a nonempty finite intersection does not exist. Or provide an example of one if it does exist. I am struggling with this, and I'm working with a half open set being considered neither open or closed.

Answer (score 3):

*Providing that $\mathbb R$ is endowed with the usual topology*

The intersection of two open subsets $A, B$ of the reals is an open subset $C$. Either $C$ is empty... and indeed $C$ is finite. Or $C$ is not empty, but then it contains a nonempty interval and $C$ is therefore infinite. *It even has the power of the continuum.*

Comment: I don't really know what a mathematical way is... jocking! More seriously, what in my answer seems not mathematical?!?

Comment: the lack of numbers throws me off, but i think you're right. Thank you! I'm new to a lot of this proofy stuff

Comment: Power seems like a really strange word for cardinality; or is this common somewhere (I see it here for the first time as far as I can remember)?

Comment: @mrtaurho This is a standard wording. https://builds.openlogicproject.org/content/second-order-logic/sol-and-set-theory/power-of-continuum.pdf